# Problems with use of "ExecutorCompletionService" with Callbable vs. Runnable

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I have been working with the example code from the ExecutorCompletionService and put together the following example code.  The code in solve() works as expected and prints
`1

2

3

4

5`


The code in solve2() doesn't print anything and in fact never exits.  It doesn't matter whether ecs is constructed before or after submitting the jobs to the ExecutionService.

Is there no way to use the CompletionService construct with FutureTasks?  I have rewritten my production code to get() the results of the FutureTask directly, rather than trying to get() them from the ExecutorCompletionService, but it (Currently) has resulted in some messy looking stuff.  In short, what's wrong with solve2 below?  Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class sample {
public static class stringCallable implements Callable<String>{
    String mstring;

    stringCallable(String s) {mstring = s;}
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mstring;
    }
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Callable<String>> list = new ArrayList<Callable<String>>();
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    Executor e = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    list.add(new stringCallable("1"));
    list.add(new stringCallable("2"));
    list.add(new stringCallable("3"));
    list.add(new stringCallable("4"));
    list.add(new stringCallable("5"));

    try {
        solve(e, list);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println ("Starting Solver 2");

    try {
        solve2(es, list);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static void solve(Executor e, Collection<Callable<String>> solvers)throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(e);
    for (Callable<String> s : solvers)
     ecs.submit(s);
    int n = solvers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String r = ecs.take().get();
        if (r != null)
            use(r);
    }
}

static void solve2(ExecutorService e, Collection<Callable<String>> solvers)throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    for (Callable<String> s : solvers){
        FutureTask<String> f = new FutureTask<String>(s);
          e.submit(f);
    }
    CompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(e);
    int n = solvers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String r = ecs.take().get();
        if (r != null)
            use(r);
    }
}

private static void use(String r) {
    System.out.println (r);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `solve2`, when you create a `ExecutorCompletionService` using the existing `ExecutorService`, it's submitted tasks are ignored by the wrapper because it uses a separate `LinkedBlockingQueue`. The submitted tasks are not inherited. So, your code blocks when you do `ecs.take().get();` because the `ExecutorCompletionService` doesn't have, itself, any submitted tasks.

Also, you don't need to specifically create FutureTask's to submit to the `ExecutorCompletionService`. These Future tasks already are created for you, internally. That's why you get a `Future<String>` when calling `ecs.take();`.

Given this, your `solve2` function is completely useless. You are already doing it correctly in `solve1`.

Comment: Thanks.  Solve came directly from java site.  A coworker and I couldn't figure out why the second version (which is essentially how we were doing it in our code) wouldn't work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would implement it:

```
static void solve2(ExecutorService e, Collection<Callable<String>> solvers)throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    CompletionService<String> ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(e);
    for (Callable<String> s : solvers){
        ecs.submit(s);
    }
    int n = solvers.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        String r = ecs.take().get();
        if (r != null)
            use(r);
    }
}
```

The ExecutorCompletionService is "just" a wrapper around ExecutorService, but you must submit your callables to the ECS, as the ECS will take the result of the callable, place it onto a queue. This result is then available via a take() or poll().
If you submit a callable directly on the ExecutorService, the ECS cannot know about its completion.
If you look in the javadoc of ECS, it says exactly the same things + good example (even better explanation). I advice you also to take a look at the source code java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService

Comment: Yeah the ECS javadocs is where I got the first solution from, but we had a a preconception about the FutureTask thing that was getting in the way.

Thanks!